# Load UNC path in RadFileExplorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, unc

I have a RadFileExplorer and I want to load the folders under a UNC path to display on my explorer. My problem is, it has error "Failed to map the path \... ". I search all over the net but not find any solutions.

Here is my code:

web.config:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="UNCPath" value="\\Sample\Operation\Documents"  />
</appSettings>
```

---

aspx.cs:

```
RadFileExplorer1.Configuration.ViewPaths = new string[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UNCPath"] };
```

---

CustomProvider:

```
public override DirectoryItem ResolveRootDirectoryAsTree(string path)
{
   // Get all folders and filters folder to show

   DirectoryItem originalFolder = base.ResolveRootDirectoryAsTree(path); --->ERROR HERE "Failed to map the path \\Sample\Operation\Documents"
}
```

How can I access the UNC path to load it in my RadExplorer? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The RadFileExplorer doesn't support this out of the box. You need to create a custom file provider and add a file handler. This KB has more info http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/details/use-radfileexplorer-with-physical-and-shared-folder-s-paths

Answer (score 0):

Whats happens if you escape the path to \\\\Sample\\Operation\\Documents\\

Comment: Replace your path value in your web.config to the one above (note the extra slashes)

Comment: You then may run into windows permissioms problems if you havent applied the necessary ones